# Implement Logistic Regression(LR) in Tensorflow,But Result looks strange when using bias but good without bias

Tags: tensorflow, logistic-regression

I tried the LR for sparse dataset using the tensorflow package(0.7.0)
The following is part of my procedure:

```py
weight_values=generateWeight([trainset.feature_num,1],name='weight')  
bias=init_bias([1,1],name='bias')  
sp_shape=tf.placeholder(tf.int64)  
sp_indices=tf.placeholder(tf.int64)  
sp_ids_value=tf.placeholder(tf.int64)  
sp_features_value=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)  
Y=tf.placeholder('float',name='Y')  

sp_ids=tf.SparseTensor(sp_indices,sp_ids_value,sp_shape)
sp_values=tf.SparseTensor(sp_indices,sp_features_value,sp_shape)
\#Z=tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse(weight_values,sp_ids,sp_values);
Z_b=tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse(weight_values,sp_ids,sp_values)+bias  
predict_op=tf.sigmoid(Z_b,name='result')   
\#cost=tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(Z,Y)
cost=tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(Z_b,Y)
train_op=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

...
```

but I find the results is wired when using the bias,using the bias I find the abs(cost) became larger and larger and even the abs(bias) also became larger and larger.

IN the early iterations the results like this :

```
1 labels[-1], j-sample 1662,  i-bias 0.100000 cost 0.761811, z_b 0.045602    
2 labels[1],  j-sample 823,   i-bias 0.084886 cost 0.653277, z_b 0.081396  
3 labels[-1], j-sample 20802, i-bias 0.089683 cost 0.826316, z_b 0.088132  
4 labels[-1], j-sample 25965, i-bias 0.074462 cost 0.806052, z_b 0.074804  
5 labels[1],  j-sample 10322, i-bias 0.059276 cost 0.664358, z_b 0.058433  
6 labels[-1], j-sample 23946, i-bias 0.064129 cost 0.795182, z_b 0.067642  
......
```

**but with more iteration the results like this :**

```
270504 labels[-1], j-sample 446,   i-bias -248.318787 cost -250.818787, z_b   -250.818787    
270505 labels[1],  j-sample 10314, i-bias -248.328781 cost 248.306259,  z_b -248.306259  
270506 labels[1],  j-sample 3820,  i-bias -248.318787 cost 247.367340,  z_b -247.367340  
270507 labels[1],  j-sample 2922,  i-bias -248.308792 cost 248.276184,  z_b -248.276184  
270508 labels[-1], j-sample 20797, i-bias -248.298798 cost -255.061432, z_b -255.061432  
270509 labels[-1], j-sample 19755, i-bias -248.308792 cost -251.686646, z b -251.686646   
270510 labels[1],  j-sample 9528,  i-bias -248.318787 cost 248.405624,  z b 248.405624
```

However if I donot use the bias the results looks good, what maybe the problems and I wonder the reasons very much.

Can anynone help me, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of “embedding_lookup_sparse” is wrong.
Look at this[source code of embedding_lookup_sparse](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cb17d1b0e2b581b5da1d9597b7929ba764749d38/tensorflow/python/ops/embedding_ops.py#L280)

the default value of combiner is "mean", but if you want to get the w * x, which x is a sparse data, you should set the combiner is "sum", not the "mean".
So I think this is your main problem.